# problems with mapping firebase documents: argument passed to call takes no arguments

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i do have an interesting issue with Xcode 14.3, firebase 9.6.0.

My code is getting documents from firebase and I want to map the received documents to a custom struct "Game"

```
struct Game: Identifiable, Codable {  
    @DocumentID var id: String?             // -> UUID of firestore document
    var nr: Int?
    var status: String?
    var league: String
    var homeTeam: String
    var homeTeamLogoUrl: String?
    var guestTeam: String
    var guestTeamLogoUrl: String?
    var runs: Runs?
    var scheduledDate: Date
    var startTime: Date?
    var endTime: Date?
    var ballpark: String
    var city: String
    var scorerID: String?
    var score: Count?
    var bases: BaseStatus?
    var inning: Int?
    var inningHalf: String?
    var inningResults: [InningResult]?
}

func getLiveGames(country: String, league: String, season: Int) async {
    // declare temporary list of live games
    var liveGames = [Game]()

    let leagueRef = db.collection("liveGames")
    
    let snapshot = try? await leagueRef.getDocuments()

    if snapshot != nil {
        for docs in snapshot!.documents {
            do {
                let result = try docs.data(as: Game.self)
                print(result)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }  
        }
    } else {
        self.errorMessage = "No documents in 'liveGames' collection"
        print(self.errorMessage)
    }
}
```

Even I have followed the descriptions from firebase help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping?hl=en

Xcode shows the following error message: Arguments passed to call takes no arguments.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyFga.jpg)

Even Xcode shows this error message, it does compile and run my code.

Does anyone has experienced the same behavior?

The very interesting part of this is, that with a little different code, Xcode does not compile and does not run the code. But that's the way how I really want to code ...

```
func getLiveGames(country: String, league: String, season: Int) async {
    // declare temporary list of scheduled games
    var liveGames = [Game]()

    let leagueRef = db.collection("liveGames")
    
    let queryLiveGames = try? await leagueRef.getDocuments()
     
    if queryLiveGames != nil {
        liveGames = (queryLiveGames!.documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Game? in
        let result = Result { try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Game.self) }

        switch result {
        case .success(let game):
             if var game = game {
                 // A game value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot
                 self?.errorMessage = nil
                 liveGames.append(game)
                 return game
             }
             else {
                 // A nil value was initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
                 // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil
                 self.errorMessage = "Game document doesn't exist."
                 return nil
             }
         
        case .failure(let error):
        // A liveGame value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot
             switch error {
                 case DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, let context):
                 self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
                 case DecodingError.valueNotFound(_, let context):
                 self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
                 case DecodingError.keyNotFound(_, let context):
                 self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
                 case DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let key):
                 self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(key)"
                 default:
                 self.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
             }
             return nil
        }
        }))
    } else {
        self.errorMessage = "No documents in 'liveGames' collection"
        print(self.errorMessage)
    }
}
```

Xcode-Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: One comment; don't use `try ?`. Use do/try/catch

Comment: it must have to do something with the firebase version. Previously I have been working with firebase package 9.6.0. After upgrading to 10.9.0 the error messages after compiling the code do not show up any more ....

Answer (score 1):

Add FirebaseFirestoreSwift as a dependency to the Xcode target and `import FirebaseFirestoreSwift`.